# Is preview feature for video server-side only or can be made also on front?

Tags: javascript, html, video, media-player, preview

I'm developing a player using HLS/Dash. I want something similar to youtube preview feature.
It is technically possible to take a screenshot from avideo element using canvas, but it requires to actually change current time of the player, which is undesirable.
There are only two approach I can think of:

1. Make screenshosts on the server side with ffmpeg.
2. Create seperate hidden video and generate preview screenshots using it.
   What is the best approach? Maybe something else I'm missing?

[image]

Comment: the usual way to do this would be extract frames serverside and then either deliver them ondemand for the scrubber or as a single image and display just the relevant portion (see plyr.io for an example of the sprite based approach https://github.com/sampotts/plyr#preview-thumbnails)